# Is decorator pattern suitable here

Tags: java, decorator

So I have a couple of classes, `A`, `B`, `C`, ... `N`. And a couple of possible properties, `setP()`, `setQ()`, `setR()`, ... `setZ()`. Now, each class can have a different combination of properties:

```
A          B          C          N
- setX     - setR     - setP     - setY
- setY     - setZ     - setQ     - setZ
- setZ                - setR
                      - setS
                      - setZ
```

all of the setters return an instance of the object itself so that chaining is possible.

im trying to find an elegant way to solve this problem. i dont want to redefine the tens of properties in each class (code duplication) and i dont wanna use inheritance since the there will be ugly, pointless intermediate classes (`BaseABCD -> setZ`) and cuz the base class setter will return an instance of type `BaseABCD` which will not allow full chaining of all properties.

here are some possible things im trying to look into:

1. somehow define each property as a decorator in an elegant fashion, and compose `A` something like `Base.decorators().addX().addY().addZ().finalize()`.
2. define all possible properties in `Base` and hide non-required properties in derived classes. I dont think this is possible.

Is any of these things possible? or is there a better idea to solve a problem like this one?

---

**More details**

The classes are basically different message types used by the application to communicate with an external system. Different messages contain different fields of different types. For instance:

```
ECHO message:
- Timestamp (DateTime)
- SourceAddress (String)

CHECK RESOURCE message:
- Timestamp (DateTime)
- Resource Identifier (Integer)

MANIPULATE RESOURCE
- Resource Identifier (Integer)
- Operation Type (Enum)
```

The messages are serialized as a string when transmitted and type information is not retained. So I chose to go with a `HashMap<String, String>`. Each property corresponds to a key within that class's hashmap. When serializing, I just iterate over all key/value entries in that class's hashmap and produce a string message representation to be sent.

However, I want to enforce types towards the caller code. So I dont want to expose a method like `A.set('RESOURCEIDENTIFIER', '123456')`. Instead I want to expose methods like `A.setResourceIdentifier(123456)` and `C.setOperation(OperationType.DELETE)`.

Internally, these setter functions are simply putting a relevant key in the hashmap and assigning a string value to it.

```
public A setOperation(OperationType operation) {
    this.hashmap.put('OPERATION', operation.name());
    return this;
}
```

There are about 40 unique field types and all messages employ a unique subset of these fields. Like `A` and `B` contain `setTimestamp()`. `B` and `C` contain `setResourceIdentifier()`. Only `C` contains `setOperationType()`. And so on.

I don't want to redefine these tens of properties in each class over and over again. That's why I want to explore the following two options:

**Option 1**
Define a `Base` class with ALL possible properties and in derived `A` class, override only the required properties to be public. This is do-able. But I want to see if it is possible to implement something like described in option #2.

**Option 2**
Somehow define decorators and a factory class such that

```
public ? getA() {
    return Base.startDecorating()
        .addTimestamp()
        .addResourceIdentifier()
        .finalize();
}

? objA = Factory.getA()
    .setTimestamp(DateTime.now())
    .setResourceIdentifier(123456);
```

Can this be possible? While writing out this question, I realized that Option 1 should be the way to go. It's simple and less error prone. But just out of curiosity I want to know if decorator pattern can be used here. After all, what I have here is a complete set of independent modules (properties) and different ways of assembling them together (the classes).

Comment: What's ugly about inheritance in this case? Can you provide more concrete example? setX Y Z isn't helpful.

Comment: Does the class or method that is creating these objects interacting with the base class or with the sub-class?  Using List as an example, does it know that it is using LinkedList versus just a List?

Comment: how about one base class with an underlying enumset to hold properties?

Comment: @Palcente. this was certainly the current implementation but i wanted to see if i could apply a decorator pattern to this problem successfully. but looks like it will be difficult to pull off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the setters of the properties have some logic in them which is shared across multiple main classes, a decorator pattern can fit and be a good design approach. If not, e.g. you are sure that all they will ever do is `this.x=x` or that each class sets a property of some type diffrently then no.

You can define a class for each of the properties, and have your main classes have variables of types of the properties classes. this way when a property is being set on the main class it delegates the job to the setter of the appropriate property class, This way you define the setters of your properties once and use them everywhere. Again, in case you have more logic then `this.x=x;` in your setters this may be the best idea.

Oh and you can still return `this` for chainning after delegating the set job to the property class.

Also, if you are lazy and care less for real time performance, you can use reflections to ease the coding of your main classes.

Answer (score 2):

A decorator is made for something that you can keep adding to.  Like a xmas tree.  But once the xmas tree is decorated, then you use common methods like `turnOn()`.  Its not made for adding new methods to an existing API.  I think you can use regular old inheritance for this.  I would also use examples like List.  Your Base class can provide the common methods that all will share, and then each other sub-class will add new methods.

To help keep things clean you can add a Factory or a Builder to make things easier.

Here are some examples.  Assuming base class is called `Base`, and sub-classes are one letter named classes, `A`, `B`, etc.

1. Factory example 1.

   `Base x = factory.getInstance(A.class);`
2. Factory example 2.

   `Map props = ...;
   Base x = factory.getInstance(A.class, props);`
3. Builder example 1.

   `Base x = new ABuilder().setX(x).setY(y).setZ(z).create();`

This involves creating a builder class for each individual sub-class.  The sub-class builder classes may or may not inherit from an abstract `BaseBuilder` class that defines a method with signature `public Base create();`.

Comment: thank you. this seems an interesting idea. i will definitely try this to see how it pans out. :)

Answer (score 0):

From the names of the properties i would guess you are trying to define different coordinate representations? Why not use one base class with all properties?

Those are actually not that much properties and you can't combine them in random permutations. So why make every thing more complex then necessary?

I don't think Decorator would be a good fit here: the sense of a decorator is to stay transparent. If you define your properties like that, you would have to check (on type or existance of the property) for each and every access.